# Tweet Button now tweeting URL

Tags: twitter

I'm using the [Twitter Tweet Button](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button).

In my application I have this code:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://localhost:3000/foo/bar/foo/bar/213/foo" data-text="I've just done stuff!" data-size="large" data-dnt="true">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

However, then I click on the button I only see the following tweet:

```
I've just done stuff!
```

What's that all about then?  Where's my URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use localhost in data-url attributes apparently due to anti-XSS

source: http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/b7d399df4ea2ba75

This may be the issue? Does it work with other URLs?

Comment: use `anything.lvh.me` to get round the problem. All resolves to 127.0.0.1